# How to add a custom field image in a block, for a style background-image: url()

Tags: views, theming, blocks, media

I'm trying to add a background image field to a block, when template-c is selected using the style property:

```
<?php
//here I can set if template AB or C 1,2,3
if ($rows[0]['field_template'] == 'Template A') {
    //template A is text left and logo right
    $show = "template-a";
}
if ($rows[0]['field_template'] == 'Template B') {
    //template B is text 2 images one right one bottom
    $show = "template-b";
}
if ($rows[0]['field_template'] == 'Template C') {
    //photo background and click video
    $show = "template-c";
    $background_image=print $rows[0]['field_slider_back_template_c'];
}
?>

<div class="work-block <?php echo $show; ?>" style="background-image: url($background_image);
<?php
    if(strpos($rows[0]['title'],'Verizon') === false) print 'color: black;';
    else 'color: white;';
?>
">
```

Is there a better way to do this?.
I tried to add `print $rows[0]['field_slider_back_template_c'];` directly on the `style="background-image: url()` without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake here -

```
  $background_image=print $rows[0]['field_slider_back_template_c'];
}
?>

<div class="work-block <?php echo $show; ?>" style="background-image: url($background_image);
```

Instead you should try -

```
  $background_image = $rows[0]['field_slider_back_template_c'];
}
?>

<div class="work-block <?php echo $show; ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php print $background_image; ?>);
```